# Can't add tables from Server Explorer to my DBML

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio-2013

I added the DBMLDataContext to my project in Visual Studio 2013. I was able to drag and drop from the Server Explorer the tables from the SQL Server that I wanted. Yesterday, while working on it, I started getting told that a column in a table was not valid. So I tried to open the DBML and Studio told me there was no valid editor for the file. So I deleted the DBML and added a new one. Now I can open it but when I try the drag/drop from Server Explorer, I get the error, "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.ComponentModel.AttributeProviderAttribute[]'". Can't find anything online about this error.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056593/drag-and-drop-from-server-explorer-to-dataset-and-dbml-designer-not-working). Tried it and it didn't work. Any other ideas?

EDIT:
I also get the error message when I try to add a new Data Source.

Comment: It seems to be a bug.Try building a new solution and then add your solution files to it and test it again

Comment: It seems like a some kind of corruption in VS enviroment. Try to repair you VS. And reboot you computer